# File count in a folder not showing accurate

Tags: bash, shell, command-substitution

I am writing a shell script to check two things at one time. The first condition is to check for the existence of a specific file and the second condition is to confirm that there is only one file in that directory.

I am using the following code:

```sh
conf_file=ls -1 /opt/files/conf.json 2>/dev/null | wc -l 
total_file=ls -1 /opt/files/* 2>/dev/null| wc -l

if [ $conf_file -eq 1 ] && [ $total_file -eq 1 ]
then
    echo "done"
else
    echo "Not Done"
fi
```

It is returning the following error

```sh
0
0
./ifexist.sh: 4: [: -eq: unexpected operator
Not Done
```

I am probably doing a very silly mistake. Can anyone help me a little bit?

Comment: Your code has trivial syntax errors. Please try http://shellcheck.net/ before requesting human assistance. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651437/how-do-i-set-a-variable-to-the-output-of-a-command-in-bash

Comment: Please note: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Comment: The error message is not consistent with the code you posted. You would get that error if the variable was empty, out you set it to `ls`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the reasons you should normally not parse `ls` is that you can get strange results when you have files with newlines. In your case that won't be an issue, because any file different from `json.conf` should make the test fail. However you should make the code counting the files be future-proof. You can use `find` for this.

Your code can be changed into

```
jsonfile="/opt/files/conf.json"
countfiles=$(find /opt/files -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec printf '.\n' \; | wc -l)

if [[ -f "${jsonfile}" ]] && (( "${countfiles}" == 1)); then
  echo "Done"
else
  echo "Not Done"
fi
```

Answer (score -1):

When you say this:

```
conf_file=ls -1 /opt/files/conf.json 2>/dev/null | wc -l
```

That assigns the value "ls" to the variable `conf_file`, and then tries to run a command called "-1" and pipe the result to `wc`  If you want to run a pipe sequence, you have to enclose it in $( ):

```
conf_file=$(ls -1 /opt/files/conf.json 2./dev/null | wc -l)
```

Next, when combining clauses in the `test` command (`[`), do it inside the command:

```
if [ $conf_file -eq 1 -a $total_file -eq 1 ]
```

However, there are better ways to do this.  You can check if a file exists with "-f", and you can just check whether the output of `ls` matches what you expect, without creating variables or running other commands:

```
if [ -f /opt/files/conf.json -a "$(ls /opt/files/conf.*)" -eq "/opt/files/conf.json" ]
```

However, it is not a friendly practice to prohibit other files.  In many cases, people might want to leave backup or test copies (conf.json.bak or conf.json.test), and there's no reason for you to block that.

Comment: The [`ls` is still useless.](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#ls)

Comment: @tripleee That's not actually true.  `xxx=/opt/files/no.such.file` will produce a string.  `xxx=$(ls /opt/files/no.such.file)` will produce an empty string.

Comment: But `[ /opt/files/conf.* -eq "/opt/files/conf.json" ]` will be true only when only that file exists. (There will be an unsightly syntax error when the wildcard matches more than one file, though.)